# Bokeh embed_multiply example returns an error

Tags: bokeh

I'm attempting to run the embed_multiple.py example from https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/embed/embed_multiple.py

Here's the error I see when I run the script:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/Users/me/test/project/Test.py", line 41, in <module>
    script, div = components(plots)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bokeh/embed.py", line 56, in components
    ref = plot_object.ref
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'ref'
```

Is there a workout to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a new example that requires the latest version of Bokeh (0.9.1), you are trying to run it with an older version.